# Using regex, separate the time value in time format

Tags: javascript, regex

Using Regex I would like to get time alone from the below `text` string. The below one is printing in  a single line. My objective is use less .js line to achieve this. Any advise would be really helpful.

```
let myArr = [];
let text = "12:30 am01:00 am10:00 am10:15 am";
finalTime = text.replace(/[^0-9: ]/g, '');
console.log(finalTime);
```

[image]

I am expecting Array values should display as below for me to choose easily or may be a json object will do

`let myArr = ["12:30", "01:00", "10:00", "10:15"]`

Comment: What if there's a `09:00 pm`? Do you just need `09:00` or `21:00` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `match` instead of replace. It will return an array of all the matches.

```js
let text = "12:30 am01:00 am10:00 am10:15 am";
let myArr = text.match(/[0-9:]+/g);
console.log(myArr);
```

Comment: Very handy and less complex !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deal with the possibility of times in the afternoon e.g. `01:00 pm`, you could use [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) and convert the resultant arrays into a string by checking for `am` or `pm` and adjusting the time as necessary:

```js
let text = "12:30 am01:00 am10:00 pm10:15 am";

myArr = Array.from(text.matchAll(/(0[0-9]|1[012])(:[0-5][0-9])\s+([ap])m/gi),
                   m => (m[3].toLowerCase() == 'a' ? m[1] : (+m[1] + 12)) + m[2]);

console.log(myArr);
```

Note I've also adjusted the regex to ensure that the times are valid; if you know they will be you can replace the regex with just

```regex
(\d\d)(:\d\d)\s+([ap])m
```

Comment: Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` with delimiter  `am` and exclude last one `['']` with `slicing`

```js
let text = "12:30 am01:00 am10:00 am10:15 am";
let myArr = text.split(' am').slice(0,-1);
console.log(myArr);
```

**P.S*:* it works only for  `am` times. if you want works for  `pm` too, use another split with  `pm` as delimiter.